# Getting unexpected output in the if and elif statement of userinput

Tags: python, one-time-password

I am trying to make an OTP generator and verifier using python. But I don't get the desired output, and even if I enter the wrong OTP it considers the first print statement and prints "welcome sir". This occurs not only on this project — it happens for me with every project. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my code:

```
import math, random
import smtplib

def sendEmail(to, content):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login('your mail', 'your password')
    server.sendmail('your mail', to, content)
    server.close()#please allow less secure app to access this

# function to generate OTP
def generateOTP() :
    # Declare a digits variable
    # which stores all digits
    digits = "0123456789"
    OTP = ""

# length of password can be chaged
# by changing value in range
    for i in range(4) :
        OTP += digits[math.floor(random.random() * 10)]
    return OTP

# Driver code
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    #print(generateOTP())
    content =   generateOTP() 
    to = 'your mail'
    sendEmail(to, content)
    print('mail sent !!')

    userinput = input('enter your otp')
    if (userinput!= generateOTP()):
        print('welcome sir')
    else:
        print('otp not recognized please enter valid otp!')
```

Comment: You are generating a random String in ```generateOTP``` how do you think you are entering the right input?

Comment: You're checking for unequal (userinput != generateOTP). But what's the logic here? You generate a new OTP and compare with the input. I don't understand the purpose of your code

Comment: ```content``` will not be equal to the return value of ```generateOTP``` in the if statement, a new OTP is generated there

Answer (score 1):

Your first if-condition checks if `userinput != generateOTP()`. The `!=` comparison operator denotes `not equal to`. So basically, your if-statement says that if the user's input is not equal to the generated OTP, print "welcome sir", which is the opposite of the logic that you want to implement.

The following code will fix the problem for you. All you need to do is replace `!=` with `==`.

```py
if (userinput == generateOTP()):
        print('welcome sir')
else:
    print('otp not recognized please enter valid otp!')
```

But again, `generateOTP` returns a random string. So I don't understand what's the point of this code. The user won't know what input to enter to get it right.

Comment: that won't fix anything, because GenerateOTP generates a random OTP everytime when it is called. So the use has to guess a random number....

Comment: Yes @jps I figured it out right after I posted the answer

Comment: You to check with `userinput` with `content`, which is already answered by @FloLie.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this piece of code:

```
userinput = input('enter your otp')
if (userinput == content):
    print('welcome sir')
else:
    print('otp not recognized please enter valid otp!')
```

Answer (score 0):

generateOTP() function generates a new OTP everytime it is called.
So even if the user enters the correct OTP, it will not validate it with the original OTP , but rather generates a new OTP and compares the user entered OTP to it, which will never be equal. Since the

> print('welcome sir')

statement is executed when the OTPs don't match , it is always triggered.

try this instead

```
userinput = input('enter your otp')
if (userinput== content):
    print('welcome sir')
else:
    print('otp not recognized please enter valid otp!')
```

Comment: it worked but what should i do when i write any thing else in the content?

Comment: the content is the string being generated. You can append any other content to your string
example : 
content = "Your generated OTP is " +  content + " . Please enter the OTP in the field to validate. "

Answer (score 0):

You are confused between `!=` and `==` in python.

`!=` means **not equal to** and `==` means **is equal to**.

This statement will check if the input by the use is not equal to the value returned by `generateOTP()`. As long as the user input doesn't match it, `userinput!= generateOTP()` evaluates to True and `"welcome sir"` is displayed

```
if (userinput!= generateOTP()):
```

Suppose I enter `'1234'` and the OTP generated is `'1243'`, `if (userinput!= generateOTP()):` is True because `'1234'` is not equal to `'1243'`.

What you probably mean is:

```
if userinput== generateOTP():
```